# Android - passing data from activity to fragment in tab view

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this code in onCreate of the activity:

```
    ...
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Monuments"),
            ElencoMonumentiFragment.class, args);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Map"),
            MappaMonumentiFragment.class, args);
    ...
```

The method addTab is defined like this:

```
public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {     
    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
    tab.setTag(info);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How can I retrive the "args" parameter (that is a Bundle) from the Fragment?

What I wont to do is to pass a String to the Fragment when I add it in the Activity, like when a call putExtra on an Intent.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Fragment you can retrieve the arguments like this for example:

```
this.grade = getArguments().getInt("grade");
```

I am retrieving an int i passed through the FragmentPagerAdapter to one of my Fragments!

Comment: This is right, I knew it but I don't know why it didn't work..  however thank you for the help!